# Specify props of a component imported from a UI library in styled-componennts

Tags: styled-components, grommet

I am using `grommet` and `styled-components`. I have a few places where I use a component provided by `grommet` and set some similar props. I want to create a `styled-components` by using that component exported by `grommet` and specify the set props using `styled-components`.

Is this possible using `styled-components`? Below is what I am trying o use.

```
import { Header } from 'grommet'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const AppHeader = styled(Header)`
    background="brand"
    height="80px"
    pad="small"
`
export default AppHeader
```

The `background`, `height` and the `pad` are not set on the `AppHeader`. I only see actual CSS props being set in the examples. So, I wanted to ask if the above is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is definitely possible to use styled-components with grommet components.

In your example, the syntax you provided to styled-components wouldn't work, so following the recommended syntax structure should do the trick as follows:

```
const AppHeader = styled(Header)`
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 30px;
`;
```

I also noticed you are trying to use grommet's props, such as `pad`, that would not work with styled-components since it accepts CSS and not grommet props, the simple way, in this case, is just to use `padding` and that should work.

Regarding the `brand` color you are trying to reference, `brand` isn't defined with CSS colors, so again that wouldn't work. If you'd like to use the `brand` color, you can always reference the theme color when defining your styled components as follows:

```
const AppHeader = styled(Header)`
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.global.colors.brand};
  height: 80px;
  padding: 30px;
`;
```

Here is a full (working) code example:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { grommet, Header, Heading, Grommet, Paragraph } from "grommet";

const AppHeader = styled(Header)`
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.global.colors.brand};
  height: 80px;
  padding: 30px;
`;

const App = () => (
  <Grommet theme={grommet}>
    <AppHeader pad="small">
      <Heading level={3}>
        <strong>Hello World</strong>
      </Heading>
      <Paragraph>Hello from a Grommet page!</Paragraph>
    </AppHeader>
  </Grommet>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image]

Comment: I guess we can only set css properties in the styled-components. But my main trouble was to be able to access the theme variable while setting the css which you have displayed in your answer. So, I have marked it as the correct answer. Thanks.